# How to get editedColumn & editedRow on a view based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want to know the current column and row that it is being edited on a view based NSTableView. The editedColumn & editedRow properties both return -1. 
Thank you.

Comment: Am not sure but have you tried [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:...];


-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;